# What is the difference between $.on('load', ...).on('error', ...) and javascript .onload/.onerror functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loading several scripts on demand (depends on the user actions).

I need to validate that script is loaded and rendered.

The jQuery solution:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.src = 'https://www.supercool.com/js.js';
s.id = 'awesomeId';
s.async = true;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);

$('#awesomeId').on('load', function () {
    // do something
}).on('error', function () {
    // do something else
});
```

Or plain JS solution:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.src = 'https://www.supercool.com/js.js';
s.id = 'awesomeId';
s.async = true;
s.onload = function () {
    // do something
};
s.onerror = function () {
    // do something else
};
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

What are the principal differences (besides the jQuery library) between those solutions (if there are)?

Please note, that:

1. I don't want to rely on some variable posted in a specific file.
2. This is not a duplicate question, about `$(element).load(...)`, `$(document).ready()`, `window.onload()` ...
3. Website supports IE8 and above

Comment: Library implementations excluded, there is no logical difference.

Comment: 1. Thanks. 2. Any reference, I could read about it? 3. can you take your comment to a separate answer, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between the two is the way they are written. The execution will perform in exactly the same way.

Comment: Thanks. But @RoryMcCrossan was 2 minutes earlier